# How to filter post types with a select field?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on a Wordpress project and have a question.
I have a layout like shown below in the link to screenshot with a select field and boxes with news (two or more different post types). I want to filter with the select the post type so there should show up only the selected. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.
[image: layout with post types]

Comment: Formatt image link into image.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine dropping the pagination and having all of your posts on a single page, one option is to use [Isotope.js](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/). In addition to being a very useful plugin, they have thorough documentation to figure out how to structure your code to get filtering working.

If the pagination is absolutely necessary, this becomes more complex. Here's the short hand-wavey version that needs testing: You can use JS to reload the page with an extra parameter added to the URL (ex: /your-page?filter=post_type_1). You'll need to register your custom URL parameter with WordPress. Then, in your PHP, you'll use that parameter data in your WP_Query (or whatever you're using to query posts) to grab only posts of that type. It would be smart to have a default, where if the filter parameter from the URL isn't present or doesn't match a post type you have in your site, you default to showing all posts.

This blog post walks through how to do this method of filtering more thoroughly: https://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/post/custom-query-string-vars-in-wordpress.